# Execute sybase stored proc from hibernate

Tags: hibernate, stored-procedures

I am having issues with executing a simple sybase stored proc from hibernate. The procedure takes some input and returns one record. I tried with the following tag in hibernate mappings file and java code.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<sql-query name="sybaseproc" callable="true">
  <return class="Myentity">
     <return-property name="next" column="next"/>
  </return>
  { ? = call nextnum(?,?) }
</sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

java code is as follows

```
Query q = session.getNamedQuery("sybaseproc");
q.setString(0,"test");
q.setInteger(1,new Integer(10));
Myentity entity = (Myentity) q.uniqueResult();
```

When I run my test. I get a error saying "Errors in Named Query sybaseproc" and the test does not run. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Padmanabh

Comment: Does your stored procedure return a result set?

Comment: Yes. There is one update and then one select statement in the stored proc. It returns a result set.

Comment: Did you solve it and do you remember how?